# SQL to retrieve only duplicated values for a certain key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres as below :

```
Key    Value
1234   QAB009
1234   QAB009
1234   QAB010
1235   QAB011
1236   QAB012
1236   QAB012
1236   QAB013
```

I want output something similar to this , only values which are repeated more than once for a certain key

```
Key   Value
1234  QAB009
1236  QAB012
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: This could have been solved with a simple Google query, upped both answers though

Comment: Yes, I agree . I missed the trick of adding second column in group by condition. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple aggregation with a *having* filter:

```
select key, value
from t
group by key, value
having Count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `GROUP` over the criteria you consider as duplicates and use `HAVING` to filter for groups with more than one row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Key, Value
HAVING COUNT(Key) > 1
```